# Change a reactiveVal twice within one observeEvent handler

Tags: r, shiny

My Shiny application runs a script build.R when the user clicks the action button. I would like to inform the user not to close the app while the script is being run. When done, the user is informed that building was successful.

Here's my minimal reproducible code:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("build", "run the buildscript"),
  textOutput("rstatus")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  reloadstatus <- reactiveVal("")

  observeEvent(input$build, {

    reloadstatus("building, do not close the app")

    # in the actual app would be source("build.R")
    Sys.sleep(1)

    reloadstatus("successfully built")
  })

  output$rstatus <- renderText({
    reloadstatus()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I guess it does not work because Shiny tries to first run the `observeEvent` till the end before altering the reactiveVal. How can I achieve my desired output (first "reloading..." second "successfully...")?

Comment: For your application, take a look at the progress notification options: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/Progress.html

Comment: I just tried it with progress but it fails when I outsource the progress part to the sourced script. `Warning: Error in .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize"): Object 'session' not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shinyjs` to update the content of message.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("build", "run the buildscript"),
  p(id = "rstatus", "")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$build, {

    shinyjs::html("rstatus", "building, do not close the app")

    # in the actual app would be source("build.R")
    Sys.sleep(1)

    shinyjs::html("rstatus", "successfully built")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```